# What is the best way to trigger an redux action if the props changed after the react 16.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to trigger some redux action to store some state into the redux(cache some state) after the props have changed. With the releasing of react 16.3, a lot of life cycle functions in the React have changed. Previously, I put this into the `componentWillReceiveNextProps()`. However, it seems that there is no good way to do that. Currently, I do something like this:

```
const MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.name !== prevState.name) {
      nextProps.cacheState(prevState.someState) // this function will dispatch a redux action
      return {
        someState: nextProps.someState // the someState will changed after this function
      }
    }
    return {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that this is not a good way to dispatch an action in the `getDerivedStateFromProps()` since it cause some side effect. So what is the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: how about `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: @riwu I have tried that. However, all of these two hook function will run after the state has been updated, so that the prevState will be lost.

Comment: that's not true, see my answer below. Also, are you trying to implement undo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`:

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.name !== prevState.name) {
    this.props.cacheState(prevState.someState) 
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it directly before or after the `setState({ name: newName })` call in your function.